# Add Dynamic port at particular position using GO JS

Tags: javascript, gojs

Here is the sample code for adding new dynamic port in the left side.
Currently I need to set the dynamic port at some particular location.
Please guide me to achieve this.
I try to bind the alignment property but it not work properly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs@2.3.7/release/go.js"></script>
<div id="allSampleContent" class="p-4 w-full">
  <script id="code">
    function init() {
      const $ = go.GraphObject.make;
      myDiagram = new go.Diagram("myDiagramDiv", {
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true
      });
      myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", e => {
        const button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
        if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
        const idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
        if (myDiagram.isModified) {
          if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
        } else {
          if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.slice(0, idx);
        }
      });

      function makeButton(text, action, visiblePredicate) {
        return $("ContextMenuButton", $(go.TextBlock, text), {
          click: action
        }, visiblePredicate ? new go.Binding("visible", "", (o, e) => o.diagram ? visiblePredicate(o, e) : false).ofObject() : {});
      }
      const nodeMenu = $("ContextMenu", makeButton("Add left port",
        (e, obj) => addPort("left")), );
      const portSize = new go.Size(8, 8);
      const portMenu = $("ContextMenu", makeButton("Change color",
        (e, obj) => changeColor(obj.part.adornedObject)), makeButton("Remove side ports",
        (e, obj) => removeAll(obj.part.adornedObject)));
      myDiagram.nodeTemplate = $(go.Node, "Table", {
        locationObjectName: "BODY",
        locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
        selectionObjectName: "BODY",
        contextMenu: nodeMenu
      }, new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify), $(go.Panel, "Auto", {
        row: 1,
        column: 1,
        name: "BODY",
        stretch: go.GraphObject.Fill
      }, $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
        fill: "#dbf6cb",
        stroke: null,
        strokeWidth: 0,
        minSize: new go.Size(60, 60)
      }), $(go.TextBlock, {
        margin: 10,
        textAlign: "center",
        font: "bold 14px Segoe UI,sans-serif",
        stroke: "#484848",
        editable: true
      }, new go.Binding("text", "name").makeTwoWay())), $(go.Panel, "Vertical", new go.Binding("itemArray", "leftArray"), {
        row: 1,
        column: 0,
        itemTemplate: $(go.Panel, {
          _side: "left",
          fromSpot: go.Spot.Left,
          toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
          fromLinkable: true,
          toLinkable: true,
          cursor: "pointer",
          contextMenu: portMenu
        }, new go.Binding("portId", "portId"), $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
          stroke: null,
          strokeWidth: 0,
          desiredSize: portSize,
          margin: new go.Margin(1, 0)
        }, new go.Binding("fill", "portColor")))
      }), );
      myDiagram.linkTemplate = $(CustomLink, {
        routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
        corner: 4,
        curve: go.Link.JumpGap,
        reshapable: true,
        resegmentable: true,
        relinkableFrom: true,
        relinkableTo: true
      }, new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(), $(go.Shape, {
        stroke: "#2F4F4F",
        strokeWidth: 2
      }));
      myDiagram.toolManager.clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData = {
        name: "Unit",
        leftArray: [],
        rightArray: [],
        topArray: [],
        bottomArray: []
      };
      myDiagram.contextMenu = $("ContextMenu", makeButton("Paste",
        (e, obj) => e.diagram.commandHandler.pasteSelection(e.diagram.toolManager.contextMenuTool.mouseDownPoint), o => o.diagram.commandHandler.canPasteSelection(o.diagram.toolManager.contextMenuTool.mouseDownPoint)), makeButton("Undo",
        (e, obj) => e.diagram.commandHandler.undo(), o => o.diagram.commandHandler.canUndo()), makeButton("Redo",
        (e, obj) => e.diagram.commandHandler.redo(), o => o.diagram.commandHandler.canRedo()));
      load();
    }
    class CustomLink extends go.Link {
      findSidePortIndexAndCount(node, port) {
        const nodedata = node.data;
        if (nodedata !== null) {
          const portdata = port.data;
          const side = port._side;
          const arr = nodedata[side + "Array"];
          const len = arr.length;
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (arr[i] === portdata) return [i, len];
          }
        }
        return [-1, len];
      }
      computeEndSegmentLength(node, port, spot, from) {
        const esl = super.computeEndSegmentLength(node, port, spot, from);
        const other = this.getOtherPort(port);
        if (port !== null && other !== null) {
          const thispt = port.getDocumentPoint(this.computeSpot(from));
          const otherpt = other.getDocumentPoint(this.computeSpot(!from));
          if (Math.abs(thispt.x - otherpt.x) > 20 || Math.abs(thispt.y - otherpt.y) > 20) {
            const info = this.findSidePortIndexAndCount(node, port);
            const idx = info[0];
            const count = info[1];
            if (port._side == "top" || port._side == "bottom") {
              if (otherpt.x < thispt.x) {
                return esl + 4 + idx * 8;
              } else {
                return esl + (count - idx - 1) * 8;
              }
            } else { // left or right
              if (otherpt.y < thispt.y) {
                return esl + 4 + idx * 8;
              } else {
                return esl + (count - idx - 1) * 8;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return esl;
      }
      hasCurviness() {
        if (isNaN(this.curviness)) return true;
        return super.hasCurviness();
      }
      computeCurviness() {
        if (isNaN(this.curviness)) {
          const fromnode = this.fromNode;
          const fromport = this.fromPort;
          const fromspot = this.computeSpot(true);
          const frompt = fromport.getDocumentPoint(fromspot);
          const tonode = this.toNode;
          const toport = this.toPort;
          const tospot = this.computeSpot(false);
          const topt = toport.getDocumentPoint(tospot);
          if (Math.abs(frompt.x - topt.x) > 20 || Math.abs(frompt.y - topt.y) > 20) {
            if ((fromspot.equals(go.Spot.Left) || fromspot.equals(go.Spot.Right)) && (tospot.equals(go.Spot.Left) || tospot.equals(go.Spot.Right))) {
              const fromseglen = this.computeEndSegmentLength(fromnode, fromport, fromspot, true);
              const toseglen = this.computeEndSegmentLength(tonode, toport, tospot, false);
              const c = (fromseglen - toseglen) / 2;
              if (frompt.x + fromseglen >= topt.x - toseglen) {
                if (frompt.y < topt.y) return c;
                if (frompt.y > topt.y) return -c;
              }
            } else if ((fromspot.equals(go.Spot.Top) || fromspot.equals(go.Spot.Bottom)) && (tospot.equals(go.Spot.Top) || tospot.equals(go.Spot.Bottom))) {
              const fromseglen = this.computeEndSegmentLength(fromnode, fromport, fromspot, true);
              const toseglen = this.computeEndSegmentLength(tonode, toport, tospot, false);
              const c = (fromseglen - toseglen) / 2;
              if (frompt.x + fromseglen >= topt.x - toseglen) {
                if (frompt.y < topt.y) return c;
                if (frompt.y > topt.y) return -c;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return super.computeCurviness();
      }
    }

    function addPort(side) {
      myDiagram.startTransaction("addPort");
      myDiagram.selection.each(node => {
        if (!(node instanceof go.Node)) return;
        let i = 0;
        while (node.findPort(side + i.toString()) !== node) i++;
        const name = side + i.toString();
        const arr = node.data[side + "Array"];
        if (arr) {
          const newportdata = {
            portId: name,
            portColor: getPortColor()
          };
          myDiagram.model.insertArrayItem(arr, -1, newportdata);
        }
      });
      myDiagram.commitTransaction("addPort");
    }

    function removeAll(port) {
      myDiagram.startTransaction("removePorts");
      const nodedata = port.part.data;
      const side = port._side;
      myDiagram.model.setDataProperty(nodedata, side + "Array", []);
      myDiagram.commitTransaction("removePorts");
    }

    function changeColor(port) {
      myDiagram.startTransaction("colorPort");
      const data = port.data;
      myDiagram.model.setDataProperty(data, "portColor", getPortColor());
      myDiagram.commitTransaction("colorPort");
    }

    function getPortColor() {
      const portColors = ["#fae3d7", "#d6effc", "#ebe3fc", "#eaeef8", "#fadfe5", "#6cafdb", "#66d6d1"]
      return portColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * portColors.length)];
    }

    function save() {
      document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
      myDiagram.isModified = false;
    }

    function load() {
      myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
    }
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
  </script>
  <div id="sample">
    <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="width: 600px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black; position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); cursor: auto;">
      <canvas tabindex="0" width="898" height="748" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2; user-select: none; touch-action: none; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: normal; width: 599px; height: 499px; cursor: auto;">This text is displayed if your browser does not support the Canvas HTML element.</canvas>
      <div style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; width: 599px; height: 499px; z-index: 1;">
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div> Add port to selected nodes: <button onclick="addPort('left')">Left</button>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button id="SaveButton" onclick="save()" disabled="">Save</button>
        <button onclick="load()">Load</button> Diagram Model saved in JSON format:
      </div>
      <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%;height:250px">{ "class": "GraphLinksModel",
  "copiesArrays": true,
  "copiesArrayObjects": true,
  "linkFromPortIdProperty": "fromPort",
  "linkToPortIdProperty": "toPort",
  "nodeDataArray": [{"key":1,"name":"Unit One","loc":"101 204","leftArray":[{"portColor":"#fae3d7","portId":"left0"}],"topArray":[],"bottomArray":[],"rightArray":[]}],
  "linkDataArray": []}
</textarea>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the sample code base see Go examples.
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as a general suggestion you should segregate and modularize your code because it looks way too complex in a single file with transactional and business logic.

From what I read in the documentation, you need to check following things in your code:

1. In the `addPort` function, you need to set the `go.Spot.Left` property:

```js
const newportdata = {
  portId: name,
  portColor: getPortColor(),
  alignment: go.Spot.Left    <--- here
};
```

2. In the node template, include a binding for the `alignment` property:

```js
itemTemplate: $(go.Panel, {
  _side: "left",
  fromSpot: go.Spot.Left,
  toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
  fromLinkable: true,
  toLinkable: true,
  ...,
  contextMenu: portMenu,
  alignment: new go.Binding("alignment", "alignment").makeTwoWay()  <--- here
}
```

3. In your JSON model, it looks from the docs that you need to include the left `alignment` property:

```json
{
  "key": 1,
  "name": "Unit One",
  "loc": "101 204",
  "leftArray": [
    {
      "portColor": "#blue",
      "portId": "left0",
      "alignment": "Left" <--- here
    }
  ],
  "topArray": [],
  "bottomArray": [],
  "rightArray": []
}
```

I think this should solve your problem but note that this answer is just by referring the documentation of GoJS available.

Comment: I tried but its not work. its throw an error.
      Uncaught TypeError: a.Lc is not a function
       at W.set (go.js:976:73)
This error throw from go js library  while setting  the alignment

Comment: Ok, I might have missed something functionally while going through the docs. But I have not really used GoJS before so sadly I cannot help much further. Let me check if there's an easy way to resolve the error.

Comment: which version of GoJS are you using?

Comment: Go js version is 2.3.7

Comment: That is one of the recent versions so unless some breaking change was introduced here it should work. I think someone more experienced in GoJS than me can answer the question.